# Rails 4 - routing using concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-routes, activesupport-concern

I am trying to figure out how to use concerns in my routes file.

I have models called User, Project and Eoi.

The associations are:

User

```
has_many :eois
```

Project

```
has_many :eois
```

Eoi

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

I am trying to make a system to show eois that have been submitted on a project, so that they are visible only to the user that made the project.

Separately, I want to show every user all of the eois that user made (regardless of which project they are made on).

I think I want nested routes for the first scenario and then I also want eoi routes that are not nested for the second scenario.

In my routes.rb

I have:

```
resources :projects do
    # concerns: :eois, 
    member do
    resources :eois
  end
```

I also want to have:

```
resources :eois
```

How can I make this work? I can't get the hang of the examples in this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Concerns.html

I don't understand whether commendable in the example is a model or if its something I need to write to be able to have routes in two places in the routes.rb file.

My next attempt is to try to copy the gist of the example in the above link, I have

```
resources :eois#, only: [:index]
  concern :eoiable do
    resources :eois
  end

resources :projects do
    concerns :eoiable
  end
```

I'm not sure if i need to make a definition somewhere to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Route concerns are needed only when you want to DRY your routes. So far you have only one route duplication (`eoi`) so... using a concern is an overkill here.

What you actually want to do is to have 2 `eoi` controllers, one will be responsible for providing all `eoi`s, second only for that ones which are inside the project.

For better readability I'd namespace them – put one `eois_controller.rb` inside `projects` folder and named it as `Projects::EoisController`, second one - as a top-level controller, named `EoisController`. Routes would look like this:

```
resources :eois # will map to EoisController
resources :projects do
  scope module: :projects do
    resouces :eois # will map to Projects::EoisController
  end
end
```

And, of course, you might want to DRY these 2 controllers afterwards.